# Apply styled component style to a third party components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, styled-components

I am learning react and I started by using `styled-components` and `react-router dom`

But I face difficulties apply my custom  styled component to an existing component not created by me.

Here is  the code:

```html
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const NavStyle = styled.div`
  color: red;
  margin: 10px;
`;

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavStyle>
        <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
      </NavStyle>
      <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

The problem is that `color: red` is not applied, but `margin: 10px` is applied in the view. Why so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can simplify styles. No need to wrap a link with another component. Simple use `styled-components` extending with `styled()` function:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledNavLink = styled(NavLink)`
  color: red;
  margin: 10px;
`;

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledNavLink to="/">Home</StyledNavLink>
      <StyledNavLink to="/about">About</StyledNavLink>
      <StyledNavLink to="/contact">Contact</StyledNavLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: Do you know how you can accomplish this if the third party component has style props like the slider below?

 <Slider
            thumbTintColor={`${props => props.theme.colors.primary}`}
            minimumTrackTintColor={`${props.theme.colors.primary`}
            maximumTrackTintColor={`${props.theme.colors.primary}`}
          />

const StyledSlider = styled(Slider)`
What can you place here?


`

Answer (score 3):

You should set style for `a` Tag:

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";

const NavStyle = styled.div`
  margin: 10px;
  a {
    color: red;
  }
`;

const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavStyle>
        <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink>
      </NavStyle>
      <NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
      <NavLink to="/contact">Contact</NavLink>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Comment: How am I supposed to know that?

Comment: @Hairi because NavLink is a `a` tag